# Upload and read CSV file in google app engine

Tags: python, csv, upload, polymer, webapp2

I am uploading a CSV file from a form and would like to retrieve its first line in Python. I am on an App Engine application, and using webapp2 (don't know if it's relevant?).

I tried many answers that I found on forums, but none is working. I tried:

```
def post(self):
    csv_file = self.request.POST.get('csvFile')
    fileReader = csv.reader(csv_file.file)
```

But I get: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'file'`

I also tried:

```
def post(self):
    csvFile = self.request.get('csvFile')
    print csvFile

    stringReader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(csvFile))
    for row in stringReader:
        print row
```

But I get:

`C:\fakepath\my_file.csv
['C:\\fakepath\\my_file.csv']`

for my print statements (whether I do request.get or request.POST.get).

I also tried:

```
def post(self):
    content = self.request.POST.multi['csvFile'].file.read()
```

But I get: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'file'`

I also tried:

```
def post(self):
    csvFile = self.request.files['csvFile']
    file = open(csvFile, 'r')
```

But I get: `AttributeError: files`

I also tried:

```
def post(self):
    csvFile = self.request.POST['csvFile'].value.decode('utf-8')
    file = csvFile.splitlines()
    data = csv.DictReader(file)
```

But I get: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'value'`

I don't understand these errors since many of these solutions seem to work for other people.

My form looks like this (I am using Polymer):

```
<form is="iron-form" action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                          on-iron-form-submit="_formSubmitted" id="form" name="form">

                        <div class="box">
                            <input type="file" name="csvFile" id="file" class="inputfile"
                                   data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple on-tap="_chooseFile"/>
                            <label for="file" name="label">
                                <span>Choose a CSV file...</span></label>

                        </div>
```

Do you have suggestions? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem: It comes from Polymer, the object 'iron-form' does not support `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. I removed `is="iron-form"` and all worked fine.